# Changing database connection using Constructor for one user without effecting other users (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to change database connection for specific users, but the question will this affect other users?

For example, I added this Constructor to a Comment model

```
  public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        if (Session::get('database') == 'new'){
             $this->setConnection('newMysql');
        }

        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
```

If I have like 2000 users connected at the same time

Will this affect all queries for that comment model for one user with session = 'new' or it might affect other users as well?

Because from my understating, Constructor used for initialization and changing database connection might affect other users if they are using the comment model at the same time

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can find usefull information there https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/set-up-dynamic-database-connection-globally

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov
This will affect all queries for all users I am trying to do it for specific users only   by storing database value in session to know which connection to use as the example I showed, but I'm not sure if it will work for specific users, so I asked bout the Constructor  functionality if it can affect other users as well